# Animating the textview to top with increased height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have table view with a UITextView added in the footer. I want my table view to animate to top once user tap on the textview. This is done with below piece of code but I have to set the height to negative. Is there any other way of doing this?

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)iTextView {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 
                             delay:0 
                            options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        animations:^{
                             self.myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 4, 200, -160);
                             self.myTextView.text = @"test";
                             self.myTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
                             self.myTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                         }        
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             self.myLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.feedbackTextView.frame.size.height + kRunnerTopBottomMargin, kScreenWidth, 20.0f)] autorelease];
                             self.myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                             self.myLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
                             self.myLabel.text = @"default";
                             self.myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                             self.myLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
                             [self.view addSubview:self.myLabel];
                         }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call this method:

```
    [YourTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help you.

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```